# How can I add a condition to {{variable.value}} in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, conditional-statements

I want to print a value if a condition is true with `{{variable.value}}`

I don't know how to do it, I'm using divs:

```
<div ng-if="true">{{variable.value}}</div>
```

But I want to set the condition only using the value not the HTML, it's possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand, you can use ng-show: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

```
<div ng-show="variable.value">{{variable.value}}</div>
```

Comment: I think that now I understand, that I know, angular use directives to process the content, then you will use HTML even if content will not be showed. PS: Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows.

```
"use babel"

angular.module('app', []).component('home', {
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = () => {
      this.name = 'David'
    }
  },
  template: `<form name="myForm">
  <label>I agree to terms
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$ctrl.terms">
  </label><br/>
  <p ng-if="$ctrl.terms">You have agreed to terms, {{$ctrl.name}}</p>
 </form>`
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/sXSVG56chFNNdPlfdsff?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you most initialize your ng-if to test

ng-model="myStaff" ng-init="myStaff = true"

and after  you do

{{variable.value}}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="option.isVisible">{{variable.value}}</div>
```

And;

```
<div ng-show="option.isVisible">{{variable.value}}</div>
```